# Rotating an Image in Pygame

Tags: python, python-2.7, pygame

I know this question has been asked before, mostly because I have read through just about every post on here mentioning the subject, but I cannot get it to achieve the effect I am wanting. As far as I can tell, my math and code is correct. Basically, I am creating an over-the-head 90 degree shooter, and I want the player's image to rotate to face the mouse. As it is now, the image will very slightly rotate left and right, but does not fully rotate to face the mouse. As I said, I have looked through the tutorials but I am not able to figure this out. Any help or pointers would be appreciated. My code is below. Thanks!

```
    #Import pygame
    import pygame, sys
    from pygame.locals import *
    import math

    #Initialize pygame
    pygame.init()


   #System variables
   running = True
   dispWidth = 800
   dispHeight = 600
   pygame.mouse.set_visible(False)
   pygame.key.set_repeat(1, 50)

   player = pygame.image.load('resources/player_handgun.png')
   playerX = 50
   playerY = 50

   background = pygame.image.load('resources/grass.png')

   crosshair = pygame.image.load('resources/crosshair.png')

   gameScreen = pygame.display.set_mode( ( dispWidth, dispHeight) )
   pygame.display.set_caption('Zombie Shooter')
   gameScreen.blit( player, ( playerX, playerY))
   gameScreen.blit( background, ( 0, 0))

   pygame.display.update()

   #def updateScreen():
   #    playerX = playerX + movement

   #Game Loop
   while running:
     blue = (0,0,255)


     velX = 0
     velY = 0

     for event in pygame.event.get():
         if event.type == QUIT:
             pygame.quit()
             sys.exit()
         elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
             if event.key == pygame.K_d:
                 velX = 10
             if event.key == pygame.K_a:
                 velX = (-10)
             if event.key == pygame.K_w:
                 velY = (-10)
             if event.key == pygame.K_s:
                 velY = 10

     playerX = playerX + velX
     playerY = playerY + velY
     pos = (pygame.mouse.get_pos()[0], pygame.mouse.get_pos()[1])
     playerDirection = math.atan2(playerY-pos[1], playerX-pos[0])

     char = pygame.transform.rotate(player, playerDirection)
     gameScreen.blit( background, (0, 0))
     gameScreen.blit( char,(playerX,playerY))


     gameScreen.blit( crosshair, (pos[0]-16,pos[1]-16))


     print playerDirection
     pygame.display.update()
```

Answer (score 1):

`pygame.transform.rotate` takes an angle in degrees, while `math.atan2` returns an angle in radians, so you need to convert between the two.

```
playerDirection = math.degrees(math.atan2(playerY-pos[1], playerX-pos[0]))
```

Links:

- http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/transform.html#pygame.transform.rotate
- https://docs.python.org/2/library/math.html#math.atan2
- https://docs.python.org/2/library/math.html#math.degrees

Comment: I have found that usually `pygame.transform.rotozoom` does a better job at rotating images

Comment: Thanks for the response, both of you. I tried what Peter Gibson suggested, and it now rotates. The issue it is giving me now is that it rotates the opposite direciton the mouse is moving, i.e. when the image should rotate left, it turns right, and vice versa.

Comment: @CherokeeLakes easy, just negate the direction: `playerDirection = -math.degrees(...`

Comment: I am assuming this is because either the origin of the sprite should be in its middle for the rotation to look correct, or because the image is facing the wrong direction. I have looked up how to change the origin, and found nothing. So what I did, is just draw the image at its X value minus its X value divided by half. (and the same with the Y value). This did not fix the issue. I am not sure what I am doing wrong, because the code seems correct from what I have seen on    line.

Comment: @CherokeeLakes Actually, the vector from the player to the mouse pos should probably be `(pos[1]-playerY, pos[0]-playerX)` rather than the other way around, so perhaps this is where the problem lies